# Combine Subjects, CurrentValueSubject or PassThroughSubject, lose values

Tags: swift, thread-safety, combine, subject

I have been using Combine Subjects to convert data streams into Publishers, but I have encountered an inconsistency and am seeking insight into the issue.

It appears obtaining deterministic behavior in Subjects can be challenging due to the implementation of Combine. The code I have written in a playground (Swift 5.7) does not produce the expected outcome of receiving all values, `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],` after calling `.sink(receiveCompletion:receiveValue:).`

```swift
import Combine
var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

func subject() -> CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>
{
    let subject = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(0)
    Task
    {
        subject.value = 1
        subject.value = 2
        subject.value = 3
        subject.value = 4
        subject.send(completion: .finished)
    }
    return subject
}

subject()
    .buffer(size: 10, prefetch: .keepFull, whenFull: .dropOldest)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(
        receiveCompletion: { _ in print("Subscription completed.") },
        receiveValue: { value in print(" Received value: \(value)") }
    ).store(in: &cancellables)
```

We can get it to work by wrapping the value changes, or sends when using a PassThroughSubject, inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` or `Task.detached { @MainActor in }.`

[Matt Gallagher discusses a lack of thread safety guarantees in Combine](https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/twenty-two-short-tests-of-combine-part-3.html#thread-safety), and this simple example of a function returning a Subject while sending values within it aptly demonstrates the issue at hand.

How can we use Subjects to get consistent results without customizing and individually testing each use case? Using a `.buffer` or `.receive(on:)` at subscription has some effect, but the real problem is having consistent threading at the send site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this is fully solvable with PassThroughSubject or CurrentValueSubject. In both cases, if they do not have listener, they drop their values. For a related discussion, see [Collecting Publisher values with async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76273105/collecting-publisher-values-with-async/76275590#76275590). `.buffer` with `.keepFull` is not sufficient. Something has to actually call `.sink` to create demand.

You must make sure that there is a listener attached before you start calling `send`. Generally this means keeping everything on one thread (generally the main one). There just isn't a good tool for synchronizing cross-thread operations in Combine.

The feature you want is called "back pressure," and adding back pressure to "a thing like Subject" is exactly what [AsyncChannel](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md) is designed to do. That of course is a big change (moving to Structured Concurrency rather than Combine), but I've found AsyncChannel extremely robust for these kinds of problems.